# P(x = k | x > 0)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poisson-distribution

Say that $P$ is a Poisson pmf with parameter $\lambda$. I'm trying to compute $P(x=k, \lambda | x > 0)$ where $k > 0$.

Here's my approach:

$$ P(x=k, \lambda | x > 0) = \frac{P(x = k \,\& \,x > 0, 
\lambda)}{P(x > 0)}$$

But now I'm stuck on the numerator. How would I compute that?

Comment: What is $k$? Is $k$ greater than zero?

Comment: @Joseph sorry, yes, I accidentally removed that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(x=k \land x\gt 0)=P(x=k)$, since $k\gt0$.